# Udev not running inline scripts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, udev

So I'm currently trying to get `udev` to do some things (start airmon-ng) after I've connected a specific USB wifi network card. But I am having troubles getting inline scripts to work. The problem can be reproduced using the following simple example:

Create the following executable script `/test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo hello > /tmp/test.txt
```

Create the following file `/etc/udev/rules.d/85-auto-monitor.rules`:

```
# This works:
ACTION=="move", KERNEL=="wlx8416f91a5ed3", RUN+="/test.sh"

# This does not work:
# ACTION=="move", KERNEL=="wlx8416f91a5ed3", RUN+="sh -c 'echo hello > /tmp/test.txt'"
```

Use the following command to reload the `.rules` file:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload
```

I simply can't understand why the external script works but not the inline one. The inline scripts works if I run it in my terminal.

Comment: Copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116996/udev-not-running-inline-scripts

Comment: use absolute paths

Answer (score 1):

From [`man 7 udev`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html#RUN%7Btype%7D):

> RUN{*type*}
>
> Add a program to the list of programs to be executed after processing all the rules for a specific event, depending on *"type"*:
>
> *"program"*
>
> Execute an external program specified as the assigned value. **If no absolute path is given, the program is expected to live in /usr/lib/udev; otherwise, the absolute path must be specified.**
>
> This is the default if no type is specified.
>
> *"builtin"*
>
> As program, but use one of the built-in programs rather than an external one.

So, in your example your must use the absolute path to `sh` as Alex P. [mentioned](https://superuser.com/questions/1193893/udev-not-running-inline-scripts#comment1752590_1193893):
`RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo hello > /tmp/test.txt'"`